# Authomatically convert sprite images in texture atlases

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way outside there to convert a bunch of sprite images already running in a cocos2d game to an atlas.
Searching for a way to do it authomatically without touching the existing source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out an application called [Texture Packer](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). With it you can create sprite sheets (another word for atlas really) and in code you can use

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"image_name"];
```

rather than

```
CCSprite* sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
```

Before you create sprites, you'll need to add the sprite sheet's plist file from Texture Packer:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"sheet.plist"];
```

I hope this helped.